# How to define DeleteBehavior in the class inheriting from another?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I know I could use `DeleteBehavior` attribute in a property, the problem is that property is inherited.

I have the following classes:

```cs
[Table("Profiles")]
public class Profile 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}

[Table("Agents")]
public class AgentProfile : Profile
{
    // ...
}
```

And this is the migration generated:

```csharp
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Agents",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        // ...
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Agents", x => x.Id);
        // ...
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Agents_Profiles_Id",
            column: x => x.Id,
            principalTable: "Profiles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

The problem is this line:

`onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);`

How do I mark that specific FK as Restrict? I know how to do it for explicit relationships like:

```csharp
EntityTypeBuilder<AgentProfile>
    .HasMany(a => a.Cases)
    .WithOne(c => c.Agent)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

But I couldn't find out how to do that for my scenario (the inherited relationship). The migration is created (a weird behavior from EF Core IMO, I think the error should be thrown during the migration creation), but I can't update the database because I get the error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Agents_Profiles_Id' on table 'Agents' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

I know I could simply change the generated migration and change it to Restrict, but I don't want to do that, otherwise it'll be an extra step, using the FluentApi would be ideal. I also understand MS SQL Server has its own restrictions, but I'm assuming it's possible to define this behavior without having to change the auto generated migration.
How can I do so using an attribute or the FluentApi?

Using EF Core 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response by [ajcvickers](https://github.com/ajcvickers)

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<AgentProfile>()
        .HasOne<Profile>()
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<AgentProfile>(e => e.Id)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#tpt-cascade-delete